# systemd error on boot: [DEPEND] Dependency failed for ifup for virbr0/nic

Tags: boot, systemd

First time booting with systemd after upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04

I get this from systemd

```
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device sys-su...m-net-devices-virbr0-nic.device.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for ifup for virbr0/nic.
[ ***  ] A start job is running for Wait for...to Quit (1h 4min 37s / no limit)
```

`sshd` is up, so I was able to remote in and copy and paste this from `/var/log/boot.log`. How do I tell systemd that this interface is up and ready?

Comment: I had a problem like this where I left a relic in /etc/fstab trying to mount a USB drive.                                                                                                                              `/dev/sdc   /mnt/sdc1   auto        user,noatime        0 1`